# Retrieve Picture from mysql to VB,NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Please Help on retrieving the picture from my mysql database
still got an error "parameter is invalid"

```
 DTEmployee = ExecuteQuery("SELECT picture FROM employee WHERE EmpID='22'")
            Dim bytes() As Byte
            bytes = DTEmployee.Rows(0).Item("picture")
            Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
            Dim X As Image = Image.FromStream(memStream) --parameter is invalid
            Dim X2 As Image = X
            PictureBox1.Image = X2
            X.Dispose()
            memStream.Close()
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

still got no luck on retrieving the images and converting it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(DTEmployee.Rows(0).Item("picture"), Byte()))
Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

Comment: still invalid parameter on Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

Comment: there might be a problem with the picture in you mysql database? I found a thread with kind of the same problem maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033634/vb-net-insert-retreive-picture-from-mysql-database-directly-to-from-a-pictureb

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes = DTEmployee.Rows(0).Item("picture")
Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)    
Dim BMP As New Bitmap(memStream)
PictureBox1.Image = BMP
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with, Bitmap BMP AS New Bitmap(MS)? bitmap cant be use as an expression.

Comment: sorry im not VB coder, i convert this from C# code, i edit it.

Comment: its ok, but the parameter is still invalid. thanks for trying out.