# I can't retrieve image from MySQL database to VB.NET picturebox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, picturebox

I can't retrieve an image from a MySQL longblob field to a VB.net picturebox. Here is the error I am seeing:

[image: Error image]

...and here is the code I am using:

```
Dim CmdString As String = "INSERT INTO employeesmaster (name, image) VALUES(@name, @image)"
        Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(CmdString, MyConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", MySqlDbType.LongBlob)
        cmd.Parameters("@name").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@image").Value = Me.PictureBox1.Image
        Dim RowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If RowsAffected > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Image saved")
        End If
```

Comment: I have tried with so much codes to retrieve.. I dnt know where is the mistake...  I used the above written code to save the image to mysql longblob field..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033634

Comment: GoBusto .. excellent guidance...  I checked that solution and I have took dMO's answer and its working also.  But i have a doubt,... with that method what about storage space? need more space to save the image?

Comment: It's probably best to ask this via a comment on that question, rather than splitting the discussion between here and there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.net - insert/retreive picture from mysql Database directly to/from a Picturebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033634/vb-net-insert-retreive-picture-from-mysql-database-directly-to-from-a-pictureb)